# Using not equal to in Python

Tags: python, syntax-error

I have a list here

```
seq = ['soup','dog','salad','cat','great']
list(filter(lambda item: item[0]! == 's',seq))
```

I want to say that populate the list where the 1st letter in the word is not 's'.
The above one gives an error.

> error :  File "", line 2
> list(filter(lambda item: item[0]! = 's',seq))

Comment: Are you sure not equal is `! ==`?

Comment: No, it was not. it was !=. Its working now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax for 'Not equal to' is '!='

Use the code below.

```
list(filter(lambda item: item[0]!= 's',seq))
```

Comment: No problem, can you please mark it as the correct answer

Comment: sure done, thank you